# Visual Studio 2015 Professioanl is raising the following error :- Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

I have the following inside my Dev machine:-

1. Windows server r2 2012.
2. SharePoint server 2016.
3. I download/Install Visual studio 2015 Professioanl.
4. I download Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015
5. i created a new empty sharepoint 2016 project inside VS 2015 community.
6. inside the project i added a new Event Receiver.
7. i build the project successfully.

but when i click on start debugging the got this weird exception :-

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
> LoaderExceptions property for more information. SharePointProject6

here is how my SP 2016 solution looks like:-

[image]

also my project is showing this warning:-

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning
> Unhandled exception occurred while calling method
> 'projectService_ProjectInitialized' of type
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport.PackageBootstrapper,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport,
> Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Message: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> SharePointProject6 0

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

**EDIT**

here is the references

[image] :-

**EDIT-2**
when i checked my current references from the following location "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`", i got the following:-

[image]

**EDIT-3**

now i went to another machine which have visual studio 2015 installed (actually it is my dev laptop), and i copies the `Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll` from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35`, then i paste it inside my server which have sharepoint and visual studio installed:-

[image]

then i open the visual studio project, i browse for the `Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll`, and i add it inside my visual studio project, as follow:-

[image]

but i am still facing the same error. now i try running the visual studio as Admin.Plus i clear the bin folder of my project. Plus i repair the visual studio and i repair the development tools for visual studio... but when i run the project I will receive the same error...

**Edit-4**
now i have repair Visual Studio 2015, and i got these messages:-

[image]

so i am not sure if these messages can be related to the problem i am facing ?

Comment: Can you send screenshot of references (menu>Add Reference)?

Comment: @SamuelTulach thanks for your reply.. i edited my question with a screen shot of the references i have ,, all of them were added automatically except "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxinomy" which i manually add it..

Comment: When you right click on references>Add reference do you see Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services checked?

Comment: @SamuelTulach now when i right click on references>Add reference there is not any reference named "Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services " neither under extension nor under framework .. the only related reference i can see is under framework named "Microsoft.Activities.build" and it is unchecked.. so what does this mean ??

Comment: @SamuelTulach can you advice on my above comment please?thanks

Comment: Maybe look there: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/117828 It looks like the same problem when loading Microsoft.Activities dlls. Also try to check Microsoft.Activities.Build. In this time I am not have access to windows machine, so I cant look at it.

Comment: @SamuelTulach now i add the reference named "Microsoft.Activities" to my VS project but it did not solve the problem... also when i checked my current references from the following location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5" i got the screen shot attached to my original question (please check it)..

Comment:  Thats all looks good. Maybe try to reinstall visual studio and net framework. No more ideas.

Comment: @SamuelTulach but what is the idea of re-installing VS and .net ??

Comment: Which account are you running VS on ?
Is this account a System admin ? are you running as admin?
try running as the system account and run VS as Admin and try

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan i already try running the project as admin,, and yes i am running the project using a system admin, which have full control on the machine, but this is not the problem. can you check my Edit-3 of my original question,, were i provided extra details about my case...

Answer (score 9):

1. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport` and thus `Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll` are loaded by Visual Studio (`devenv.exe`) itself, not by the component you're writing, so VS won't look for it in your project directories.
2. You could probably work around the problem by copying `Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll` into the same directory as `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowDesignerSupport`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\Extensions\WFDesignerSupport\`.
3. The best way to do it is certainly to install the missing `Workflow Manager` component of which this DLL is a part. It can be downloaded from Microsoft as described here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193448(v=azure.10).aspx

**Edit**

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx, an executable can specify in it's config file where to look for assemblies, which VS does. `devenv.exe.config` contains :

```
<probing privatePath="PublicAssemblies;PrivateAssemblies;...
```

so it should look for the dlls in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`.

Comment: so you are suggestion to navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\Extensions\WFDesignerSupport" and add "Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll" ??

Comment: If the missing DLL is supposed to be on your system, then you should use the repair option of the installer (Visual Studio ?). Copying the missing file to the directory is more a short term hack/a test.

Comment: now i already repair Visual studio multiple times... not sure what is going on ...

Comment: and to be honest i am not sure if this dll is supposed to be in my system ornot.

Comment: It's on mine, and I didn't do anything to get it. I think it comes with VS.

Comment: now i manually copies the "Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services" file from my dev PC to the sharepoint server folder named ":\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\Extensions\WFDesignerSupport\", i close VS and open it again.. try to run the project but i got the same error "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Comment: You run VS on the SharePoint server ?

Comment: I guess another file is missing ("or one of its dependencies" in error message). You could use sysinternals Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) to find it.

Comment: yes i have VS professional 2015 installed inside sharepoint server 2016 .. and the server is windows 2012 R2.. actually to be able to build sharepoint solutions i need to have VS installed on the same sharepoint server (but this is not my question),,,

Comment: and why i have missing files? although i have installed sharepoint 2016 + VS 2015 + workflow managers without any problems during the installation and configuration..now i am thinking of this scenario,, i have installed VS 2015 and its development tools prior to installing workflow manager.. so could this be the problem?i mean should i try to un-install VS and re-install it again.. although i have repair VS after installing the WF manager....which seems did not solve my problem..

Comment: can you check my "Edit-4" section, which shown the result after i repair my Visual Studio 2015..

Comment: 1. Reinstalling VS shouldn't do more than repairing it. I'd rather repair (or uninstall/reinstall) Workflow Manager.

Comment: 2. The messages concerning C++ Redistributables don't matter here (probably Windows Update pulled a more recent version)

Comment: 3. The usual way files are missing is when you uninstall some component whose files are in use (Windows logs them as to be deleted at next reboot) and then reinstall without rebooting first. The installer notices the files are already present, but they are deleted when you finally reboot.

Comment: so what are your suggestions to have all the missing files. without having to worry about manually adding them one by one??...

Comment: Looking into Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll with Reflector, it has no additional dependencies, so it is this assembly that is not found.

Comment: and where i need to add it? i mean under which folder ??

Comment: Use the MSI on the VS Pro DVD/ISO (see other answer) or copy it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies` folder.

Comment: so you mean to copy "Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll"  inside  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" folder ??? if the answer is Yes.. then from where i can get this file.. as i have installed VS and workflow manager from the web i do not have DVD or iso.. can u advice please.

Comment: It's the file you copied from your dev laptop to your SharePoint server and did try to add a reference to in your project.

Answer (score 3):

`Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll` now comes with `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio`, whose installer is on the Visual Studio Professional install DVD/ISO, in the `\packages\sptoolsDependencies\enu` folder.
It doesn't exist on the Community Edition.

Install/repair on `WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi` will install the required files both in the GAC and in the References folder.

**Update**

`WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi` is also found under `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4830FC51-95F2-48CB-A7D9-8FCF262F4204}v2.0.50408.2\packages\sptoolsDependencies\enu`on my machine.

Comment: now i have Visual Studio 2015 professional and i have workflow manager 1.0 installed.. so you are saying to repair the workflow manager ??  and i do not have and DVD/ISO i have download everything from the web..

Comment: You may download the `vs2015.pro_enu.iso` file from the official Microsoft site https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48147. You'll then need a program like VirtualCloneDrive to open it in a virtual DVD drive. You can also create an offline installation directory from the `vs_professional.exe` online installer (see the Installation Instructions on the download page).

Comment: You have to repair `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio`, not `Workflow Manager` nor `Workflow Manager Client`. These are 3 separate installers.

Comment: now i checked my control panel, and seems i do not have a tool named "Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio".. while i have both "Workflow Manager" & "Workflow Manager Client".. so do i need to install "Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio" ??

Comment: VS is composed of many small installer files (there are 342 on the DVD). Most of these are dependents of another one, and don't appear in the Control Panel. `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio` is shared between VS 2012, VS 2013 and VS 2015. Right-click > Repair on `WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi` restore files I deleted in the `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0` folder.

Comment: 1. Many things are installed on your machine that don't appear under Control Panel.

Comment: 2. They are normally installed/removed as part of a bigger component that appears under Control Panel.

Comment: 3. You may nonetheless interact with them with a right click on the .msi file. That's not usually necessary nor recommanded.

Comment: 4. `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio` was installed on my machine when I checked the option "Microsoft Office Developer Tools" of the VS 2015 installer.

Comment: 5. I removed the `Microsoft.Activities.Design.Services.dll` file from the `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0` folder on my machine, and checked that repairing `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio` restored it correcly. I didn't try to remove the same file from the GAC because it didn't want to risk breaking my installation.

Comment: 6. On my machine, Windows registered the installation of `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio` under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\15CF03842F59BC847A9DF8FC62F22440\InstallProperties`. `S-1-5-18` is a "A special account used by the operating system.". `15CF03842F59BC847A9DF8FC62F22440` is the product key on my machine. Not sure it would be the same on another machine.

Comment: unfortunelty i uninstall VS 2015 professional and re-install it again did not fix the problem ,, still i am getting this error when "Error  Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information" when i try to run my project !!!

Comment: Right-click > Repair on `WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi` does the work on my machine. You *might* find the msi under `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4830FC51-95F2-48CB-A7D9-8FCF262F4204}v2.0.50408.2\packages\sptoolsDependencies\enu`.

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall nor repair of `Visual Studio 2015` nor `Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015` doesn't seem to have any effect on `Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio`.

Comment: so you mean i need to repair the WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi??... but again in my case i have downloaded everything so i do not have WorkflowManagerTools_x64.msi inside my machine.. so how i can repair this tool in my case.. since i have download the whole workflow manger...

Comment: I have already given 3 different ways to get the .msi. Pick the one you prefer...